# How to combine data to create new dataframes

Tags: r

I am trying to combine elements of a data using R.  Here I show an example of the type of data I am using.

## data.example

```
# number  pos.number alter1 alter2 
  1         320
  2         321       350   450
  3         500       490   400
  4         560             300
  5         400       450
```

I need to combine pos.number data with alter1 and alter2. The combination need to be done with replacement of data element. 
For example if I choose the data.call[2,3] , then this element must replace data.call[2,2], and so the combination of alternatives should create new dataframes.
Note: The combination not only involve 1 element at a time if not can involve 2 or more.

I am reading my data using :

```
      data.call <- read.table("data.example",col.name=c("number","pos.number","alter1","alter2"),fill=TRUE)
```

and this create NA over the places which has no element. Of course the combination with NA must be avoided.

Comment: If you type in data.call$alter1[2,3] what does it display?

Comment: I edited the question. It mus be data.call[2,3]